# full page js slide next section over current

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I'm working on a website with the [FullPage.JS](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/backgrounds.html) script.
What I want is that the next section slides over the previous one.
[See this example](http://www.protest.eu/nl/heren/)
I tried to make the position fixed in css and changed animation values in the jquery.fullpage.js

It should be something simple but i can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a similar effect with the backgrounds using the `background-position:fixed;` property as you can see in the [backgroundsFixed.html](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/examples/backgroundsFixed.html) example in [fullPage.js examples folder](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/examples).

But I think you should better change to [pagePiling.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/), [its brother plugin](http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/presenting-pagepiling-js-a-new-plugin-to-create-a-scrolling-pile-of-sections/) which allows you to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi @alvaro i wanted to add Pagepiling effect only in one section inside fullpage.js, do you mind helping me out.

Comment: @undefinedtoken you can not do it I'm afraid.